# Crop an image from x and y position using sorl_thumbnail

Tags: django, python-3.x, crop, sorl-thumbnail

Python 3 and Django 1.11.15

Hi,

I'm using a plugin which returns an x and y position from an image besides usual image dimensions (width and height). I'd like to crop this image with sorl_thumbnail in Python using x and y position (like image cover on Facebook). I think there is a function, maybe like `cropbox()`, but I don't understand how it works. Please someone can help me, giving me an example of using this function or another solution to crop an image with these data. 
Thanks to all.

Here is a sample of my code in models.py:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import default as sorl_thumbnail

def as_headline(self):
    image = self.image
    img_size = "600"
    x = 133
    y = 0
    x2 = 328
    y2 = 180
    cropbox = (x, y, x2, y2)
    return sorl_thumbnail.backend.get_thumbnail("path/to/file.jpg", img_size, cropbox=cropbox).url
```